# Can I define an EntityType but not make it available as a Feed?

Tags: odata, olingo

I'm using Odata/Olingo v2.  I have several Entity Types defined including `Product` and `Category`. A `Product` can have many `Categories`.

**I would like to ONLY make `Products` available as a Feed/Resource.**  I thought I could accomplish this by defining a `Category` Entity Type and Association but not adding the `Categories` `EntitySet` and `AssociationSet` to the `EntityContainer`.  I also created a `NavigationProperty` between `Product` and `Category`.

This appears to be valid EDMX, at least Olingo's `EdmxProvider.parse()` does not object.  However, when I post a `Product` with a collection of `Categories` to the `Products` feed Olingo throws an exception from `EdmEntityContainerImplProv.getAssociationSet()` because it expects to find an `AssociationSet` for `Categories`

*Is there a way to accomplish this in OData/Olingo v2?*

Edit: It's not an option to make `Category` a `ComplexType` because I need to have a collection of them and that's not possible in OData/Olingo v2

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with olingo implementations, so cant point you to methods/whatever.

But in general: if you want an entity to be accessible as a set (be it as `/Product('123')/ToCategories` or just `/CategorySet`), you need the according EntitySet in your metadata and in your implementation.

You can, however, limit your implementation to *only* respond when used via navigation property.

As an example: on an Abap implementation, the method implementing category get_entityset has the information, that it is accessed via navigation property from another entity (or even a path) including keys. Here, you can throw an exception or just return an empty set, if you decide you don’t want to offer direct access to `/CategorySet`